# Reversing the digits of a number in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program in which I have to reverse a number using the below logic.

```
N = 321
enable_print = N % 10
while N > 0:
    if enable_print == 0:
        enable_print = 1 
    elif enable_print == 1:
        print(N % 10, end="")
    N = N // 10
```

This works great for numbers that do not have trailing zeroes. The problem arises when the number has trailing zeroes, for example:

```
when N = 32100, output = 0123
```

Is there an error in the code above, due to which I am not able to remove the first zero in the output?

Comment: `int(str(32100)[::-1])` :-)

Comment: You set `enable_print=1` as soon as it becomes 0, so only the first zero gets skipped. You probably want to evaluate it inside the loop? (assuming you want to make this code work, the other methods are simpler)

Comment: @ScottHunter that will leave you with 00123 when you reverse 32100, which seems like not something OP wants.

Comment: What should this print if N=0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reverse string methods are all nice and clever, but I think pointing out the error in OP's code will be just as useful, if not more than providing completely different code snippet that does the same job.

You set `enable_print` to 1 in the first iteration, so you will never skip more than 1 trailing 0. You need to set it to 1 first time you encounter non 0 value.

```
N = 3002100

enable_print = False
while N > 0:
    if not enable_print:
        enable_print = (N % 10 != 0)
    if enable_print:
        print(N % 10, end="")
    N = N // 10
```

Comment: This does not work with `N = 0`

Comment: @RiccardoBucco neither does the OP's code and question is about a different problem.

Comment: The OP's code is wrong, that's why the SO question was opened. Also, technically `0` is a number with trailing zeros. But as you wish, I only gave you the opportunity to further improve your code. You can leave it like this if you prefer

Comment: @RiccardoBucco As someone replied to you already, OP did not tell us what should happen for N = 0. The code runs and OP was pretty specific about which part of code he wants fixed. While I'm all for fixing _obvious_ problems in the code even if not mentioned in the question, this is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
print(int(str(N)[::-1]))
```

Comment: *I have to reverse a number using the below logic*. I think the point of task for him is not to stringify number and reverse string

Comment: Probably not an issue in this case, but interesting nonetheless, with large floats this may turn into a problem: `str(10000000000000000000000.0)[::-1] == "22+e1"`

Answer (score 0):

It seems more straight forward to eliminate the "leading" 0's first, and then you don't have to worry about them:

```
while N>0 and N % 10 == 0:
    N = N // 10
while N > 0:
    print(N % 10, end="")
    N = N // 10
```

Comment: Corner case: this code does not work with `N = 0` ;) But the user can easily handle it with an initial `if` statement

Comment: @RiccardoBucco : Hard to claim "does not work" when OP hasn't said what should happen in this case.  (The code in the question behaves as this code does when N=0.)